# Proper way to make prediction with Keras model trained with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I have trained a model applying some image augmentations by using ImageDataGenerator in Keras as follows:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=60, 
        width_shift_range=0.1,
        height_shift_range=0.1, 
        horizontal_flip=True)
train_datagen.fit(x_train)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=7),
    steps_per_epoch=600,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=callbacks_list
)
```

How should I make predictions with this model? By using `model.predict()` as shown below?

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

Or should I use `model.predict_generator()` where an ImageDataGenerator is applied on `x_test` where `x_test` is unlabelled?

If I use `predict_generator()`: How to do that?

What is the difference between two methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`predict_generator()` is a convenience function that makes it easier to load in the images and apply the same preprocessing like you did for your training samples. I recommend using that rather than `model.predict`.

In your case simply do:

```
test_gen = ImageDataGenerator()
predictions = model.predict_generator(test_gen.flow(# ... your params here ... #))
```

Comment: in the test_gen should I use the same augmentations like the train_datagen.?

Comment: predict_generator() has and argument called steps. What is that for and how to choose it.?

Comment: @Sreeram TP You want to predict on images that are not augmented. But you need to apply the same preprocessing (normalizing etc) that you have applied to your training samples.

Comment: The steps parameter defines how many batches your generator should yield. For prediction you set steps = #samples / batch size. This needs to divide without remainder. With this value for steps you ensure you predict on every sample of your training set, but not more than one time.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I should run predict_generator() with test_gen where it has no augmentation.?

Comment: If so how is model,predict() and model.predict_generator() different from each other.?

Comment: Exactly. You instantiate a new ImageDataGenerator() with **no** augmentation (since you don´t want to alter your test samples) but all the preprocessing that you have applied to your training data. I.e. `rescale=1./255` if you have done so for your training data. Otherwise your predictions would be off.

Comment: As far as I understand `predict_generator` is simply a convenience function. It makes it much easier to get proper predictions without verbose coding.

Comment: Will the accuracy of the predictions made by the model get effected on either of the cases.?

Comment: No. It won´t. Given that you apply the same parameters (i.e. preprocessing). The samples itself need to be the same. Either function then gives you the same result.

Comment: This is to be to be expected since you get predictions. They have shape (#samples, 1).

Comment: I made predictions right with `predict_geneator()` but it looks different than the one made with `predict()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155145/discussion-between-petezurich-and-sreeram-tp).

Comment: It's a little old but I have a question. Should I call fit() ?